# Windows on scroll firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I cannot understand why is this code:

```
$(window).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function() {
    alert("aa");
});
```

The alert triggers twice when you scroll on page...

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Here is a codepen, just scroll on the page :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBNPvR

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be firing once for me in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m

Comment: odd...it's maybe just my mousewheel that is giving me trouble...

Comment: i tried to scroll twice and it fired twice.. so maybe the problem is your mousewheel.

Comment: I too am having trouble reproducing the issue. I tried using my touchpad. I will try with a mouse. edit: The trigger only occurs once for me when using a mouse.

Comment: Alright thanks guys, it's probably my mouse...I'll try with another mouse when I have the chance...

Comment: @Stephen does this occur in all web browsers for you?

Comment: @jason just tested in firefox it seems to be working, only chrome that seems to doing it twice

Comment: its firing twice because if you scroll through the DOM by using a mouse wheel your triggering both events.  why aren't you just listening for the standard scroll event?